# Measuring functions that are defined almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is a function that is defined almost everywhere, and $g$ and $h$ are function that are defined on all of $R^n$ in such a way that  $g=f \text{ almost everywhere}$ , and $h=f\text{ almost everywhere}$.

Then prove that if $g$ is measurable then $h$ is also measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lebesgue-measurable sets $A_1,A_2$ must exist with:

- $\lambda(A_1)=0=\lambda(A_2)$
- $g1_{A_1^c}=f1_{A_1^c}$
- $h1_{A_2^c}=f1_{A_2^c}$

Then also $A=A_1\cup A_2$ is Lebesgue-measurable, and this with:

- $\lambda(A)=0=\lambda(A)$
- $g1_{A^c}=h1_{A^c}$

Since the Lebesgue-measure is complete the function $h1_A$ is measurable.

If moreover $g$ is measurable then  $h1_{A^c}=g1_{A^c}$ is measurable, and also $h=h1_{A^c}+h1_A$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by 1Ac my guess is that it is an indicator function . But I am not sure, also could you say why have you claimed that $\lambda(A_1)$ = 0 ?

Comment: It is indeed the indicator function.Statement "$g=f$ a.s." is equivalent to the statement "$A_1:=\{x\mid g(x)\neq f(x)\}$ is a null set" (i.e. $\lambda(A_1)=0$).